# QProcess does not finish under windows 10 "bash on ubuntu on windows"

Tags: c++, windows, bash, qt, windows-10

I have a simple Qt programm which start's another program with `QProcess::execute()`.
It works under Windows (MSVC 32/64, Mingw-32), Linux (GCC), MAC (CLang).
But if I try to run it in a bash under Windows (Bash on ubuntu on windows) the call to `QProcess::execute()` never returns.
I've also tried to use `QProcess::start()` but neither the `QProcess::started` nor the `QProcess::errorOccured` signal is issued, and `QProcess::start()` also never returns.

Is there some incompatibilty with this configuration?

The programm was compiled with GCC 4.8.4 and Qt 5.7 for Linux

The programm looks like this:

```
#include <QProcess>
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv)
  QStringList args = app.arguments().mid(1);
  int retcode = QProcess::execute("programm", args);
  if (retcode == 0)
  {
   // do something here 
  }
  return retcode;
}
```

"programm" is an executable located some where in the search path.

Comment: Try `startDetached()` instead. I/O redirection is pretty flaky in Qt.

Comment: Specifically, I/O redirection is pretty flaky in Windows. Qt does the best it can when dealt a gratuitously broken API.

Comment: @IInspectable: This may work, but I need to wait for the process to finish, how is this done in Qt (platform independend) with only a PID?

Comment: @KubaOber: The problem does not occur on windows but on Linux. So maybe it's a problem of the Linux subsystem or maybe Qt detected the wrong environment (Windows instead of Linux).

Comment: There's no way to compile Qt successfully on Linux with a wrong mkspec, so that's not going to happen by accident :)

Comment: Please fix your question. You say that the problem happens on "bash under Windows (Bash on ubuntu on windows)" - what does that even mean? Are you running it on linux or on windows? If you're using a virtual machine, it's not very relevant. Make sure we can understand exactly what your environment is.

Comment: It's like I have said: I run a native linux application in a bash which uses the new linux subsystem under windows!
It's NOT a virtual machine!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396